# Stuck on moving GCP project to an organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, access-rights

I'm trying to move a GCP project (on a private account) to a GCP organization that I manage. I know that I have to have the correct IAM rights, which I believe I do. I'm Owner, Folder Admin, Organization Administrator, Project Deleter and Project Mover in the project. I'm also Project Owner and Project Mover of the project to be moved.

But when I try to move it, I get:

> ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.projects.move) User [(organization account)] does not have permission to access project [(the project to be moved] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission

Any experiences or suggestions?

BR,
Daniel

Comment: Could you please grant the access to the organisation to the user and then test the permissions as it is displayed here - https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#grant-access . Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Daniel, I have the same issue. Have you resolved yours? Best, Piotr

Comment: @Daniel, have you found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

### 1. Target organization

Add the user (email) who owns the project to migrate from the **source** organization.

- IAM and Administration
- Manage resources
- Select the target organization
- Permissions -> Add Member

**Permission to the user in the target organization**:

> Project Creator.

You can do it through UI or Gcloud.

*Note*: Delete the line break \

```
$ gcloud organizations add-iam-policy-binding ORGANIZATION_ID \
--member user:YOUR-EMAIL --role=roles/resourcemanager.projectCreator


Success: Updated IAM policy for organization [ORGANIZATION_ID].
```

---

### 2. Source organization

**Permissions to the user in the project to be migrated in the source organization**:

> Project Mover

*Note*: Delete the line break \

```
$ gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
$ gcloud projects  add-iam-policy-binding PROJECT_ID \ 
--member user:YOUR-EMAIL --role=roles/resourcemanager.projectMover


Success: Updated IAM policy for project [PROJECT_ID].
```

Finally, migrate the current project to an organization

```
$ gcloud alpha projects move PROJECT_ID --organization ORGANIZATION_ID
```

GL

- [Granting changing](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-gcloud-manual)
- [Migrate projects](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/migrating-projects-billing)

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant permission with `roles/resourcemanager.organizationAdmin`, in order to access the organization in R/W mode, so that it can copy & delete (move) the project (and the user needs that role for **both** of the organizations). See the documentation: [Granting access to an organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/access-control-org#grant-access).

Comment: I am an organization admin at the destination already. However, the project that I'm moving is not in an organization. It's just a project tied to an individual Google account. So, unfortunately, that doesn't solve it for me.